# How to use 2 different authentication methods with Spring Boot Security 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My application uses basic authentication for spring-data-rest access (everything under "/api/**") and JWT authentication using a UserDetailsService for a client facing API (everything under the "/component" in this example). Before upgrading to Spring Boot 2 I had everything working as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public SecurityConfig( UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder )
    {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder ) throws Exception
    {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService( userDetailsService ).passwordEncoder( passwordEncoder )
                .and()
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser( "rest" ).password( "something" ).authorities( "REST" ).roles( "REST" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, SecurityProperties.SIGN_UP_URL, SecurityProperties.LOGIN_URL ).permitAll()
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, "/component1/**", "/component2/**", "/component3/**", "/component4/**" ).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, "/component1/**", "/component2/**", "/component3/**", "/component4/**" ).authenticated()
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**" ).hasRole( "REST" )
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**" ).hasRole( "REST" )
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/**" ).hasRole( "REST" )
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.PATCH, "/api/**" ).hasRole( "REST" )
                    .antMatchers( HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/**" ).hasRole( "REST" )
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .addFilter( new JWTAuthenticationFilter( authenticationManager() ) )
                .addFilter( new JWTAuthorizationFilter( authenticationManager() ) )
                .addFilter( new BasicAuthenticationFilter( authenticationManager() ) );
    }
}
```

There's a separate config for CORS stuff which I'm not concerned with right now as it was working fine before and isn't the source of any troubles now.

So with the upgrade to Spring Boot Security 2, I have tried putting everything from each type of security in 2 different WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which will get one of them to work, whichever one has the lower @Order(1) number. I followed to some extent the example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0

I'm wondering if I should get rid of this configure override with the AuthenticationManagerBuilder now? Or keep them combined into one file? I'm not sure how to go about this, does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back to this today. I abandoned the whole multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter thing and just went back to using one. Used Spring Security logging level =DEBUG showed something that was easily fixed that I was doing that Spring 5 no longer supported.